# Javascript beginner inquiry. Identified problematic line of code but dont know why it doesnt work

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I want the function NumberAddition to take a string and return an array of each number in it.  For example argument "abc64,$ 22, 22xyz0"  should return array [64, 22, 22, 0].  The 4th line in my for loop is the problem.
    It's purpose is to move i up the string after a number is indexed so that it doesn't go over the same number again.  If I delete this line the rest works fine with the problem of course being the same number being counted over and over until I naturally passes over it.
   Why, when this line is included, does only the first number get counted (in my example the return would be [64]).  I am less interested in other ways to solve it than why this line is not functioning how I had imagined it to.  Thank you!

```
function NumberAddition(str) { 
var array = [];
var nextInt;

  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    nextInt = myParseInt(str.slice(i,10));
    array.push(nextInt);
    if (nextInt != null)
    i = str.indexOf(nextInt,i) + nextInt.length -1;
    else 
      break;
  }
  // code goes here  
  return array; 

}


function myParseInt(str){                   
 for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){

  if (!isNaN(str[i]))
    return parseInt(str.slice(i));
 }
   return NaN;
}
```

Comment: is there a reson why you don´t use regex to solve this?

Comment: @juvian, well, he did say he was a beginner.

Comment: `"abc64,$ 22, 22xyz0".match(/(\d+)/g).map(Number)`

Comment: Debug `console.log("i = ", str.indexOf(nextInt,i), " +  ", nextInt.length, "-1;");`

Answer (score 3):

Numbers don't have a length; strings do.  `nextInt.length` always returns undefined, which means you're setting i to NaN. Try `nextInt.toString().length` instead.